# PowerBI · Clicked value of a table to measure

Tags: dynamic, filter, powerbi, dax

I need to pass a clicked value from a table to measure. I don't if there is come function similar to SELECTEDVALUE.

For example:

Table with airports and number of passenger. If I click in first value (Madrid) I need to show that value in a measure: "Selected Airport: " & ...code...

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible to filter from the table directly, but you could create a segment that filters on Airport field (assuming this is the name) from Table.

You then create this measure that will display the selected airport(s):

```
Measure = 
"Selected Airport "
    & CONCATENATEX (
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Airport] );
        'Table'[Airport];
        ": "
    )
```

Comment: Could you develop ? Please edit your question with a reproductible example (table names, variable names)